# PERCENTILE_CONT equivalent in apache drill

Tags: sql, apache-drill

Is there any function equivalent of PERCENTILE_CONT in apache drill?

PERCENTILE_CONT is a reserved keyword in drill but it throws an error when used.

Even functions like MEDIAN / PERCENTILE_DISC is not there in apache drill.

Answer (score 0):

*`PERCENTILE_CONT` is currently not supported in Drill.*

You can ask the [community](https://drill.apache.org/mailinglists/) if somebody has written any UDF for this.

Or you can write your own UDF for this function. Check drill [docs](https://drill.apache.org/docs/develop-custom-functions-introduction/) for details of writing a UDF.

Comment: I looked at some Drill UDF docs and found that there are no "holders" for array types.  I can't see how one could calculate a percentile in UDF that is called once per row and only allowed to store simple types in memory.